# 2 urns with 2 types of balls conditional probability

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Consider two urns: urn-1 contains 3 red, 1 black, and 3 white balls while urn-2
contains 2 red, 3 black, and 3 white balls. If an urn is randomly selected with equal chances of it being Urn-1 or Urn-2, and then a ball is picked at random from the selected urn, find the probability that either a white or a black ball is picked.

My approach to this question looks like this:
$P(U1)*P(W|U1) + P(U1)*P(B|U1) + P(U2)*P(W|U2) + P(U2)*P(B|U2) =$ Probability that the ball picked is either black or white.

Does this seem correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your derivation is correct, but it may be simplified by replacing black and white balls with *grey* balls, since at no point in the question do black and white get treated separately. So urn $1$ has $3$ red and $4$ grey balls, and urn $2$ has $2$ red and $6$ grey balls.
$$P=\frac12\left(\frac47+\frac68\right)=\frac{37}{56}$$